# how to compare joda Datetime in hql

Tags: java, jpa, jboss7.x, jodatime, hibernate-4.x

consider this hibernate field:

```
@Column(name="datecreated", nullable = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime dateCreated;
```

i want to run an hql query like this:

```
String query = "select ticketEvent " +
                   "from TicketEvent ticketEvent " +
                   "where ticketEvent.status = :status " +
                   "and ticketEvent.dateCreated > :highestTicketCommentDate " +
                   "and ticketEvent.ticket.id = :ticketId " +
                   "order by ticketEvent.id DESC";

ticketEvents = (List<TicketEvent>) entityManager.createQuery(query)
                    .setParameter("ticketId", ticket.getId())
                    .setParameter("status", TicketEvent.Status.SAVED)
                    .setParameter("highestTicketCommentDate", highestTicketCommentDate)
                    .getResultList();
```

here highestTicketCommentDate is also a joda DateTime. but I am getting wrong results. what is the correct way to compare hql joda datetime? any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Comment: It is the right way. Tell us how the column is defined in the table, example input, and example output.

Comment: well whats hapenning is even when the two values are equal i am still getting a list, where i am just looking for a bigger value.

Comment: How do you determine that they are equal? Don't forget that the date you see in the database is in UTC. Load the date from the database using Hibernate, the print this date and also print the highestTicketCommentDate parameter.

Comment: actually both of the dates are from the database and highestTicketCommentDate is just the highest date from the list, its a poll which checks for highest comment datetime and updates. still let me get an output for both of them and post. thanks for your help

Comment: here is a log output:

dateCreated: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00 and highestTicketCommentDate: 2013-07-26T16:28:39.080+01:00
dateCreated: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00 and highestTicketCommentDate: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00
dateCreated: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00 and highestTicketCommentDate: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00
dateCreated: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00 and highestTicketCommentDate: 2013-07-26T17:00:27.223+01:00

Comment: you can see, the first time there was a difference, but then even though they were equal, i still get an update

Comment: Hmmm. Strange indeed. No idea. How is the column defined, and which database do you use?

Comment: i used postgres, but the columns are auto created like this: datecreated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,